# Json strings stored in collection in oracle apex classic report using pljson

Tags: json, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex, pljson

I have used the following query for the classic report using pljson:
the page works, but it only shows 46 records, in all cases.
Does anyone know why this limitation, or have you had a similar
experience?
Thanks for your help

```
select * from table(pljson_table.json_table((select clob001 from apex_collections 
    where collection_name = 'P204_DOREST_RESULTS'),

    pljson_varray('items[*].conceptId',
          'items[*].effectiveTime',
          'items[*].fsn.term',
          'items[*].pt.term'),
    pljson_varray('conceptId',
          'effectiveTime',
          'term',
          'termi'),

table_mode => 'nested'
));
```

Comment: This typically couples with your data. To help trace the problem, I would suggest calculating how many characters those 46 records accumulate to. That will hopefully provide a good clue as to where to look next.

Comment: Your DB version and value of MAX_STRING_SIZE database parameter may be relevant.